# How does boosting Ana work?

Tags: overwatch

Her weapon has two abilities: heal teammates, and kill enemies.

If she is damage boosted, will she heal teammates for more as well as damage enemies even further?  Does she need a healing boost from another allied Ana player to boost her healing?

Comment: Sounds like a job for SCIENCE!! I'll test later tonight if I can download the ptr fast enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She won't heal teammates for more but will damage for more. If an allied Ana uses her grenade on a teammate and you shoot an ally while they're under the affects of the buff, it will do the same amount of healing as it would if you were the one who threw the grenade. The buff doesn't stack.